# How to change dbms_xmlgen.getxml(select query) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, oracle, t-sql

We are migrating from Oracle to SQL server. There is view in Oracle database where written `dbms_xmlgen.getxml(select query)`. How we can change this in SQL server.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding functionality in SQL Server is a [SELECT ... FOR XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) query. EG from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/columns-with-the-name-of-an-xpath-node-test?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT E.BusinessEntityID "@EmpID",   
        'Example of using node tests such as text(), comment(), processing-instruction()'                as "comment()",  
        'Some PI'                   as "processing-instruction(PI)",  
        'Employee name and address data' as "text()",  
        'middle name is optional'        as "EmpName/text()",  
        FirstName                        as "EmpName/First",   
        MiddleName                       as "EmpName/Middle",   
        LastName                         as "EmpName/Last",  
        AddressLine1                     as "Address/AddrLine1",  
        AddressLine2                     as "Address/AddrLIne2",  
        City                             as "Address/City"  
FROM   HumanResources.Employee AS E  
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS P   
    ON P.BusinessEntityID = E.BusinessEntityID  
INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS BAE  
    ON BAE.BusinessEntityID = E.BusinessEntityID  
INNER JOIN Person.Address AS A  
    ON BAE.AddressID = A.AddressID  
WHERE  E.BusinessEntityID=1  
FOR XML PATH;
```